# generating an android ant file from eclipse

Tags: android, ant, projects

I have an android project containing all my activities and manifest file etc and I am referencing 2 class libraries that contain various helpers, adapters etc. The class libraries are standard java projects.

My issue is that when I use the android update project --path . to generate the build.xml and run an ant release against this it fails because there is no dependency on the 2 class libraries.

Am I missing something big with the "android" command? or do I have to manually add to the generated build.xml to add these 2 class library builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom "compile" task in your build.xml, to compile your class libraries and then compile your android project. It is not hard at all, just copy paste the compile target from /tools/ant/main_rules.xml into your build.xml and modify accordingly.

You can read up on main_rules.xml to learn how to do this for any part of android build.

Comment: thanks dood, so if I am understanding this... (I am actually an msbuild .net developer) get the main_rules.xml and overwite my build.xml and add my tasks for compiling my 2 external libraries, call them before my main app is compiled and everything is good? or am I totally out?

Comment: You just have to examine the main_rules.xml, when android does commandline (build.xml) builds, it executes the targets from this file (if they dont exist in build.xml). So just copy the compile target into build.xml, do your class library compiles, then do the android compile in that target. But yes, you are correct in your logic for this.